# Gstreamer tutorial-4 cannot run on Android due to an error about G_IO_MODULES := openssl

Tags: android, openssl, android-ndk, gstreamer

Until tutorial-3, it was done without any problems. The problem is from 4, I think it's probably an error due to changes in gnutls and openssl. If I change G_IO_MODULES in Android.mk to gnutls, it builds, but it ends as soon as it runs with the following error.
"FORTIFY: %n not allowed on Android"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezyTe.png)

**"FORTIFY: %n not allowed on Android"**

So, if I modify the original G_IO_MODULES := openssl, it cannot be executed with the following error. Actually there is no file in that path, just libgiognutls.a. How can I do it normally? I checked the error in the part called cebero, but I can't know how to fix it or how to fix it in Android.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4AvG.png)

```
**Build command failed.
Error while executing process E:\Android-r17\android-ndk-r17c-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r17c\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\~~\Desktop\20_07_05_touch_ppt\MyApplication\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\~~\Desktop\20_07_05_touch_ppt\MyApplication\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/~~/Desktop/20_07_05_touch_ppt/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\~~\Desktop\20_07_05_touch_ppt\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk GSTREAMER_JAVA_SRC_DIR=src GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID=E:\Android-17.0\gstreamer-1.0-android-universal-1.16.0.tar\gstreamer-1.0-android-universal-1.16.0 GSTREAMER_ASSETS_DIR=src/assets C:/Users/~~/Desktop/20_07_05_touch_ppt/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/libtutorial-4.so}
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : tutorial-4 <= tutorial-4.c
GStreamer      : [GEN] => gst-build-arm64-v8a/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [COMPILE] => gst-build-arm64-v8a/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [LINK] => gst-build-arm64-v8a/libgstreamer_android.so
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'E:/Android-17.0/gstreamer-1.0-android-universal-1.16.0.tar/gstreamer-1.0-android-universal-1.16.0/arm64/lib/gio/modules/libgioopenssl.a'
make: *** [buildsharedlibrary_arm64-v8a] Error 1**
```

This is the full code of Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := tutorial-4
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := tutorial-4.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gstreamer_android
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

ifndef GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID
$(error GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID is not defined!)
endif

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/arm
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/armv7
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),arm64-v8a)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/arm64
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/x86
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86_64)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/x86_64
else
$(error Target arch ABI not supported: $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))
endif

GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build/
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/plugins.mk
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_PLAYBACK) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS)
G_IO_MODULES              := openssl
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS      := gstreamer-video-1.0
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer-1.0.mk
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are mixing different versions of the gst-examples/gst-docs repositories and your downloaded GStreamer binaries.  If you download the latest stable GStreamer binaries (1.16.2 at time of writing), you should build from the 1.16 branches of gst-examples and gst-docs to match.

GStreamer master has moved to openssl instead of gnutls for all of its ssl needs and gst-examples and gst-docs tutorials have been updated and will be incompatible with the 1.16 version of GStreamer.

For the "FORTIFY: %n not allowed on Android" issue have a look at this upstream issue: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/cerbero/-/issues/146
Make sure you are building with at least 1.16.1 and that you have done a from scratch build of your application removing all *.o and *.so files.